# MAC c++ control interactive Command Line Tools

Tags: c++, macos, command-line, interactive

I want to control the unzip command from my c++ code. My problem is that if the ZIP File I want to unzip is password encrypted, the unzip tools askes for the password.

So I need to give it the password from my c++ code and press enter, but I want my code to do that automatically.

So here is what I got till now, but when I run it, first the system() command will be executed and then the program goes on, but it does not write the password into the terminal when unzip askes for it :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include </System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CGEvent.h>
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    using namespace std;

    system("clear");

    //----------------------------------------------

    {
        system("unzip /Users/das_virus/Desktop/NeuerOrdner2/M1/Auswahl.zip"),
        cout << "a";

        /*CGEventRef event1, event2, event3, event4;

        event1 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL,(CGKeyCode)0,true);
        event2 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL,(CGKeyCode)0,false);
        event3 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL,(CGKeyCode)36,true);
        event4 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL,(CGKeyCode)36,false);

        ProcessSerialNumber psn;
        GetFrontProcess(&psn);

        CGEventPostToPSN(&psn,event1);
        CGEventPostToPSN(&psn,event2);
        CGEventPostToPSN(&psn,event3);
        CGEventPostToPSN(&psn,event4);*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I hope someone can give me an answer :)

Comment: Use the `-P password` command line switch?

Comment: Im not so common with this site till now, sorry. I will try my best but i did not see that you posted that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-P password` command line switch to pass the password as an argument.